# Enable Http Options Preflight Request For ASP.NET Web Forms ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have an ASP.NET web form application with a couple of  API controllers.
One of my controllers gets a request from a different domain. Since this request contains an Authorization header the browser sends a preflight request (HTTP OPTIONS).
At first, I tried to add the following in the web config :

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers " value="WWW-Authenticate"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, authorization, Content-Type"/>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But it didn't work, and the browser failed with "405 - method not allowed" error.
Only when adding the following code to global.asax I successfully received the preflight request

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow‌-Credentials", "true");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

The thing that bothers me is that this code enables preflight request for all web API controllers, and I want to enable it only for one of my controllers.
I know I can solve it using a function with [HttpOptions] annotation, but I don't want to add it for each function in the controller. Is there a way to enable it for all controller functions?

Answer (score 2):

Add this method to the Global.asax.cs and put this code

```
using System.Web;

namespace Example
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Nice Blog For you](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2012/05/14/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf/)

Comment: Thank you for very much for your help, I don't know why but the EnableCors doesn't work for me. My project is web forms and not MVC, so I don't have  WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: @Tal Humy, but your question contains Web Api and its not possible that web api project doesn't have WebApiConfig.cs. If your project is web forms then please edit your question with appropriate keywords so other stackoverflow visitors will not be confused.

Comment: I have added for your reference only u can use attribute which also i have mention before controller or method @Tal Humy

Comment: @D-johnAnshani I can't understand your last comment, can you please rephrase it :-)?

Comment: in Api Controller Also We can  define Cors @TalHumy

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is what I did (As you can see in my question) and it worked. but If I understand correctly it will enable cors for all api controllers.  can I limit it to a specific controller? @D-johnAnshani

Comment: Please Accept it and up vote also if its help @TalHumy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176244/discussion-between-d-john-anshani-and-tal-humy).

Comment: For Specific see this @TalHumy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope-rules-for-enablecors